# What interaction shown in this Feynman diagram and is it possible?

Tags: particle-physics, feynman-diagrams

I saw the following Feynman diagram in my textbook, not sure if a typo or something I don't know:
[image]
Just to clarify, the "e" on the upper left does not have any superscript. I am not sure if such a particle exist.

Answer (score 1):

If time flows left to right in this diagram, then this is electron-neutrino scattering, by Z exchange.

If time flows from the bottom, then this cannot be true, unless each pair of particles in this diagram is an anti-particle and a particle. (From charge conservation)

Note: When we write "$e$", and not "$e^-$", we mean the electron, and it is understood as such.

Comment: On your note at the bottom, do you suggest that the "$e$" and "$e^-$" signify electron throughout? It appears hard to believe because both are present in the same diagram.

Comment: time up the positive y axis, then it is neutrino antineutrino going to e+e- ( oposite to the arrow are antiparticles). time down the y axis e+e- to neutrino antineutrino still  the Z  exchanged

Comment: With Z as the mediator, this diagram can be seen regardless the direction of time as long as the arrows of the fermionic lines are consistently referring to anti states